# Leaflet.Draw - geoJSON to Kml

Tags: javascript, leaflet, kml, geojson, leaflet.draw

I have made a map using the Leaflet Draw plugin which allows the user to download their drawn items. These drawn items are exported as GeoJSON using the following code from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/d30c44b081be31aea483):

```
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
        // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
        var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();

        // Stringify the GeoJson
        var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + 
        encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

        // Create export
        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + 
        convertedData);      
       document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.geojson');
}
```

This works perfectly, but it would be even more ideal if the GeoJSON was converted to .kml before being exported. I am aware of the [toKml](https://github.com/mapbox/tokml) plugin but I am struggling to get it to work (I am still quite new to all of this). Where would I add:

```
var kml = tokml(geojsonObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would convert your `data` object to KML with `tokml(data)` and use the resulting string in the data URL, with the appropriate MIME type and file name :

```
var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();
var kml = tokml(data);

var convertedData = 'application/xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(kml);

// if you want to use the official MIME type for KML
// var convertedData = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
// encodeURIComponent(kml);

document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData); 
document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', 'data.kml');
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikoshr! The part I was going wrong with was definitely the correct MIME type. Just note that I had to change "(data);" to "(kml);" at the end of the convertedData line and now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @JohnGIS Thanks for spotting that